# solr like search using text_en

Tags: solr

I am using Solr. 
I need to search those entries which matches  the provided keyword
the functionality should be similar to the sql query like %keyword%
MY type file : text_en
I use *face* , it is fetching data as facebook (which is correct) 
also in addition im also fetching keywords 
like "facing" (which is incorrect) .

My idea is to get all keyword like "%face%"

how will I do this?
Im using SOlr 4.4
My solr schema is below:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should disable stemming if you don't want to match "facing".

Instead you can use EdgeNGramFilterFactory to index substrings of words

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
```